# Unity のコルーチンのような機能を async/await を使って実装するにはどうすればいいでしょうか

Tags: c#, game-development

基底クラスに仮想関数 virtual OnUpdate() が定義されていてユーザーはこれを派生クラスでオーバーライドして処理を実装するとします。
この OnUpdate() を Unity のようにコルーチン化して非同期で同時に実行されるようにしたいのですが await/async を使って実装する場合 virtual メソッドに async キーワードを付けて定義すればいいでしょうか。

```
class Base {
    public async virtual Task OnUpdate () {
    }
}
class Derived : Base {
    public async override Task OnUpdate () {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

まず virtual メソッドに async キーワードを付けるのは言語として OK です。派生クラスで override しても問題ありません。これで問題なく動作します。あと追加情報として async キーワードはメソッドのシグネチャーに含まれません。
ただし上記のように実装すると2つ問題があります。
1つ目： await が存在ないメソッドに async をコンパイラーが警告を出します
2つ目： 普通と異なる書き方をしなければならない戻り値の Task （または `Task<T>` ）がスマートでない
さらに言えばユーザーは非同期処理されるかどうかはあまり興味が無く async や Task を見たくないのが本音です。
というわけでここは Non-Virtual Interface イディオムを使って書き換えるとエレガントに書けます。

```
class Base {
    public async Task Update () {
        await Task.Run (() => {
            OnUpdate ();
        });
    }
    protected virtual void OnUpdate () {
    }
}
class Derived : Base {
    protected override void OnUpdate () {
    }
}
```

virtual OnUpdate() はこれまで通りの書き方で非同期実行されるようなりました。

Comment: 以上、自作自演でお送りしました。この辺どう実装するのがいいのか結構試行錯誤をしたので StackOverflow に還元です。他のゲームプログラマーのお役に立ちますように。もっと良い方法を思いついた人は突っ込んで下さい。

Comment: 非同期メソッドは、慣例として「～Async」という名前にします。
この場合、UpdateAsyncです。メソッド名にAsyncを付けることにより、それが非同期であることを明確化できます。
Updateのままでは、同期メソッドのつもりで使用してしまうかも知れません。

Comment: オフトピですが末尾にAsyncを付ける命名規約にはもの凄く反対です。昔あった変数名に型名を入れるのと同じぐらい愚かだと思います。そもそも同名のAsyncの無い関数を提供しないし私の書くプログラムでは絶対に入れません。